# Copying and pasting from a .py to Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I copied some code from a .py to Jupyter. I think that this has caused some errors in my code. What are some of the things that one must check when doing this? Does it make sense to first copy to notepad or something and then check it. What am I looking out for when checking my code? I can't see to find any way to distinguish between spaces and tabs in Jupyter, is this doable?

Comment: What errors in particular are you seeing? It might be related to formatting, or it might have to do with the environment that Jupyter sets up for your code.

Answer (score 0):

you might just be facing a formatting issue and 4 spaces = 1 tab so you can count that way or erase all spaces and tab it into place, either way, should work.  other than that if it works in the py file it should work in Jupiter make sure you have all your imports

Comment: I think you are right. Could you explain this a bit more? Are you saying that if a .py has 4 spaces and I copy and paste it into a Jupyter notebook that the same code will have one tab?

Comment: yes it should a tab is just 4 spaces unless u speficly state in the complier but otherwise a tab or 4 spaces equal the same

Comment: honestly you should just be able to copy and paste it into Jupiter though if it's working inside of pycharm or another similar IDE but also make sure you have your imports a great way to check is going on here https://repl.it/languages/python3 and you can test your code in a new ide that will be able to let you know if its working

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to copy in smaller chunks to validate sections/modules/functions of the code in Jupyter cells?  I'd start there.

Otherwise, I think you're already on the right track.  There may be a problem with the indentation, but there could also be an issue with line endings.  You'll want to use an editor or IDE that can show these to check.

Comment: Yes certainly feasible (and will do this) but I suppose my question is...why doesnt copy and paste work? What happens when we copy all the code from a .py and paste it into a Jupyter notebook?